# Woocommerce api list all products now returning all

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the woocommerce-api for node (js)
and for some reason no matter what I try this block of code keeps only returning 10 products instead of the whole list.

does anyone have any advice. 
Thanks in advance.

```
WooCommerce.get('products', function(err, data, res) {
    if (res !== null) {
        allItems = JSON.parse(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: I imagine it has something to do with pagination. Can you please post the JSON being returned to you?

Comment: Is there a default pagination then ?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell you without seeing your json data and headers

Comment: It is a bit of a data dump so here is the raw data before I do the JSON.Parse http://pastebin.com/YxSeVjWK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to pass parameters, like [`per_page`](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#list-all-products), to retrieve more than the default 10.

Try:

```
WooCommerce.get('products?per_page=50', function(err, data, res) {
    if (res !== null) {
        allItems = JSON.parse(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing that for me :) Feel super silly now.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the API docs [here](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#list-all-products), you'll see that you can provide optional parameters to your request to get the desired result.

According to this modify your request to this and try -

```
WooCommerce.get('products?per_page=50', function(err, data, res) {
    if (res !== null) {
        allItems = JSON.parse(res);
    }
});
```

This should return you 50 projects for example.